# How can I prevent bodies intersection in box2d (ios)?

Tags: ios, xcode, box2d

I am making a game in xcode using box2d. When I create a body(circle) it starts to fall down. When it is at the ground, another body(also circle) falls down on it and then it all goes bad. For a moment these bodies intersect each other and the next moment they bounce in opposite directions. That makes all physics awfull. I also tries to change densities, fricton and restitution parameters, but nothing helped. Please help

Comment: What step length are you using? Usually 60 steps per second (step length 1/60.0 sec) gives reasonable results.

Comment: Altering step is a good idea as you are already seeing them bounce as required.

Comment: i'm already using 60 steps. maybe i should change velocity and position iterations parameters? now they are 8 and 3.